# How to deploy the Custom list page in survey list in SharePoint 2013 programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, survey-list, newform

I need to add a custom list page in survey list using c#,
Please suggest some idea to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: What exactly you mean by custom list page? is it some thing like Edit/New form or some View of list?

Comment: @AkshayRandive , i mean , i need to add one page named as preview.aspx.
if i am doing in sharepoint designer (pls refer image).Instead of doing that i need to create by using c#.